# How to generate a GUID, that includes the device ID for an ESP32 on c# Nanoframework

Tags: c#, esp32, nanoframework

I am implementing a heatingcontroller on an ESP32, for that I have several classes (TemperatureSensor, Thermostat, ValveController etc.) because there may be more than one of each I want to give each one a unique ID. I would liek to do that using tjhe Guid class, but I want it to include the ESP 32 device ID, so that I have globally unique ID's for each class instance, that can be tied to the hardware device that the class has been instantiated on.

My question is how I can access the device ID in Nanoframework?

So far, I got stuck writing the code because I cannot find a way access the ESP32's ID

Answer (score 0):

Have u considered using the MacAdress of the device ?

Which nanoFramework device are you using exactly, according to the [nanoFramework Docs](https://docs.nanoframework.net/devices/Iot.Device.Bno055.Info.html), there are some devices which support chipID out of the box.

Comment: I am using an ESP32-WROOM-32 (D1 Mini) from AZ-Delivery

Answer (score 0):

To access ESP32 "unique id" which is the MAC address of the device, check this class property [NetworkInterface.PhysicalAddress](https://docs.nanoframework.net/api/System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.html#System_Net_NetworkInformation_NetworkInterface_PhysicalAddress).

Note that the MAC address of an ESP32 can be reprogrammed, unless you protect it by burning the respective fuse.

Using the Guid class will give you a truly unique ID. But that you already know...